# Add identities to a user with gitlab admin command

Tags: gitlab, identity, gitlab-api

So I'd like to add an ldap identity to a new user when I create them. I know the command to create a user is:

```
curl -X POST \
      'https://[company domain]/api/v4/users?private_token=xxxxxxxxxxx' \
      -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
      -H 'content-type: application/json' \
      -d '{ "email": "test3@test.com",
      "username": "test3username",
      "password": "12345678",
      "name": "test3name"
      }'
```

but I would like to add on some identities to the user as well, specifically an LDAP uid.
I tried adding this to the end after name, but it didn't work:

```
"identities":[
  { "LDAP_uid":"cn=1234567890,ou=employees,ou=test,o=company.com"
  }
  ]
```

Am I typing it in wrong? Or do I need a valid LDAP uid in order for this to work?

If this isn't possible, could someone direct me on how to add an identity to a user after they have been created using the command line?